# Непонятая кодировка при парсинге с VBulletin

Tags: кодировка, java, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с проблемой, нужно спарсить ники с одного форума на VBulletin, там разрешены всякие хитрые символы в нике. Записать всё это нужно в файл.

Пробовал так:

```
String secondString = new String(buf.getBytes("Cp1251"),"UTF-8");
```

Но остаётся такая вот белиберда в файле:

```
 Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР
```

При смене кодировки через Notepad++ становится лучше, но всё равно остаются квадраты такие:

> Кот,ЙОР�?К,Ðreaml�?l

Как решить проблему?

Comment: http://demo.seovb.com/forum.php - вот нашел демо VBulletin. В теге meta указана кодировка ISO-8859-1

>><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

Попробуйте с ней поработать.

Comment: Неа,не помогло.
http://forum.wowcircle.com/
Вот этот форум.

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях я пробую [декодер имени Темы Лебедева](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/) - он по куску:

> Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР
> °РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР 
> пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР пїЅ?
> Рљ,ГђreamlпїЅ?l,пїЅ?Р»РёР°РЅ,Р™РћР

Говорит, что это кодировка: **CP1251 → UTF-8**

Comment: Пробовал и другие декодеры.Результат одинаковый - остаются всякие �?.

Answer (score 0):

Подобный пїЅ засветился у меня в реестре по пути HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-500\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections

Его крякозябры обрабатываются перекодировкой UTF-8-1252. Но перекодировка в лоб не помогает. Похоже Utf символы распадаются на 2 части. По крайней мере искомое мной слово, имело в 2 раза больше символов. Если просто нужно понять, что там можно воспользоваться http://www.online-decoder.com/ru У меня очень много благодарных слов о них. Как они это делают - большой вопрос.

пїЅ они не могут обработать. Возможно это перенос строки.

И похоже, когда в эту западноевропейский декодер 1252-utf-8 попадает 1251 образуется злополучный пїЅ.

В инете к примеру полно сайтов-клонов с изначальной кодировкой 1251, пострадавших от клонирования через 1252-Utf-8.

В реестре эти пїЅы для Винды безразличны, но мы, к сожалению, прочитать их не можем, а скопировав вывод с экрана - теряем информацию.